# What's the difference between target :TargetName and target "TargetName" in CocoaPods Podfile?

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

Using CocoaPods, what's the difference between

```
target :TargetName do
    # Some pods...       
end
```

and

```
target "TargetName" do
    # Some pods...       
end
```

The [CodoaPods Podfile Syntax Reference](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#target) shows the first as an example, but the `pod init` Terminal command creates the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:TargetName` denotes a [Symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Symbol.html) while `"TargetName"` or `'TargetName'` denotes a [String](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html).

In this case, they should be pretty much equivalent. The value you pass to the `target` is probably being converted to a string internally. However, the semantics of these types are very different. Strings are for storing and manipulating free form text, while symbols are more like keywords, a text version of integer constants.

If you aren't sure which to use, you probably want a string.